# Facebook is not showing any of my messages

Tags: facebook

So for some days now I can't view any of my messages on Facebook. The chat in the bottom works, but when someone sends me a longer message/non-IM message here's what happens:

- I get a notification on the top, under messages
- I click the notification
- I get taken to the messages screen, the title is displayed and no messages. Even if there used to be multiple ones, there is nothing now.

I get email notifications for all Facebook message activity, so I can still read and reply, but I can't actually view it on Facebook itself. If I click the link in the email it gives me the same result: no message.

Here's a screenshot of a message thread that has over 8 messages:
[image: screenshot]

I am using Chromium 11.0.696.71 (86024) on Ubuntu 10.04, and both Ubuntu and Chromium tell me that I am up to date. I have cleared my cache and rebooted several times, nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried another browser? (such as the stable chrome build)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would check the following:

- Check that the build of Chrome you are using is stable. If not, use a build that is stable.
- Check if the problem still exists when using a different browser
- Check if the problem still exists when using a different computer (if possible)
- Disable any plugins that you may have installed.

If the problem still exists then according to this [Facebook FAQ Article](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=200392993337184) you should report the problem by completing [this form](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=Inbox_not_loading) (You must be logged in to Facebook to see this form.)

Facebook Help Article for completeness:

> **My Messages are not loading.**
>
> If you are seeing a blank page when
>   accessing your Messages, please follow
>   these steps:
>
> 1. Make sure that you are using the most recent version of your internet
>      browser. Click here for information
>      about updating your browser.
> 2. Try manually refreshing the page a few times (Ctrl+r on PCs; Cmd+r on
>      Macs).
> 3. Check if this issue is occurring on a different computer as well.
>
> If the problem persists, please submit
>   a report [here](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=Inbox_not_loading).

Comment: Disabling plug ins did it, and for the record it was the 'better PopUp blocker' plugin that failed. I got it cause Chromium slips up very often on popups. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your are using Google Chrome, it's an extension. Some extensions are blocking it, like "Better Pop-Up Blocker" or "Ad Block". Hope this helps.

If you want to keep the extension - go into the extension's options and add http://www.facebook.com to the whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

you may have installed A CHROME app called BETTER POP UP BLOCKER This causes problems in reading messages and other issues on FB with chrome, remove it and try

Comment: Please read everything, including the comments, before posting. The OP already stated that it was "Better Pop-Up Blocker".